# CakePHP ignores Content-Type setting on response

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In my controller action, I have this:

```
$pdf = $this->Invoice->makePdf($invoice);
$this->response->charset('UTF-8');
$this->response->body($pdf);
$this->response->type(array('pdf' => 'application/x-pdf'));
$this->response->disableCache();
$this->response->send();
```

However, no matter what I do, CakePHP always sends the data as `text/html; charset=utf-8`. I have also tried

```
$this->response->header(array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-pdf'));
```

But it still sent it as `text/html`. How can I force the response to be sent using the content type above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing `$this->response->type(array('pdf' => 'application/x-pdf'));` stores/replaces the content type for the associated key as mentioned in the [api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeResponse.html#_type). Use `$this->response->type('pdf');` to set the type.

Edit: Also don't call `$this->response->send();` just return the response object `return $this->response;` and let the dispatcher handle the sending.